# How to get a list of background processes in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, ps

I need to get a list of background processes in freebsd, but i don't know how. 
I've tried to use ps command,

```
ps -ax
ps -e -j
```

but I haven't found properties which describe background processes.
+Tried to use top command, but I've got no result :(

Hmm, I guess that i should see a priority of a process, and if this process has less priority than non-background analogue, so we can conclude that there is a background process.

But that's just a guess...

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "background process"? Do you mean processes that have no controlling terminal? Processes that share a controlling terminal with your process but aren't in the foreground? Or something totally different?

Comment: Processes that have no controlling terminal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command is

```
jobs
```

If you wish to have more info (not always available), it is

```
jobs -l
```

If you wish to bring job number 3 to the foreground,

```
fg %3
```

If you have a stopped job, you can resume its execution in the background by means of

```
bg %3
```

As for the BSD-style output ps ax, which, BTW, I use too, it is not too informative: it will show your background process in status S (interruptible sleep) if it is waiting for an event (user input?), or R if it is running. But this will not single them out among the bevvy of other processes. You can indeed identify it by combining this info with user ownership and terminal of execution, but I never do it this way because it is too cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you for reply :) I hope it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this may help. In freeBSD ps -a only shows the user process not all the process so to list all the process

```
ps -awx -l
```

This will list all the process you need. I hope this helps